# ssh port forwarding and multiple aliases

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, alias

I have the following ~/.ssh/config file:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host myalias
    HostName fully.qualified.domain.name
    Port 2222
    LocalForward 3690 127.0.0.1:3690
```

When I ssh to `myalias`, everything works fine:

```
$ ssh myalias
Last login: blah blah
...
```

However, I can't `ssh` to `fully.qualified.domain.name`, because the it lacks a `Host` section in the config file. I therefore changed the file so that the `Host`  section is valid for both the `alias` and the fqdn:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host myalias fully.qualified.domain.name
    HostName fully.qualified.domain.name
    Port 2222
    LocalForward 3690 127.0.0.1:3690
```

When I now `ssh` to `myalias`, I get this error message (but the port forwarding *does* work):

```
$ ssh myalias
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 3690
Last login: blah blah
...
```

1. **What exactly is happening?**
2. **How can I get rid of these messages?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ssh -vvv <host>` to debug issues.

This should work:

```
Host myalias
    HostName fully.qualified.domain.name
Host fully.qualified.domain.name
    Port 2222
    LocalForward 3690 127.0.0.1:3690
```

Edit:

For different options, use different aliases.

```
Host alias1
    HostName fully.qualified.domain.name
Host alias2
    HostName fully.qualified.domain.name
    LocalForward 3690 127.0.0.1:3690
Host fully.qualified.domain.name
    Port 2222
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could have different options for `myalias` and for `fully.qualified.domain.name` (e.g. if I wanted myalias to *not* have the `LocalForward`) ? From what I understood, `myalias` will include the options specified in `fully.qualified.domain.name`, and I don't know a way of disabling that behaviour. I don't need to do that, I'm just curious :) .